# Departure from uniformity in a continuous (time) distribution

Tags: statistics, information-theory, uniform-distribution

I know how to quantify the departure from uniformity ( or a uniform distribution) for discrete distributions. Assume you have a distribution set of P:

```
P={P1, P2, P3, ....., PN}
```

The departure from uniformity for this discrete distribution is defined as follow:

```
D= SUM(Pi * log (Pi / (1/N)))
```

Now my question is how to quantify the departure from uniformity in a time distribution which is actually a continuous distribution. I have a family of time distribution functions in the form of: (B is a parameter )

```
P(t;B) = - (t)^(B)
```

Clearly, the linear distribution is resulted once B=1.
How can I quantify the departure from uniformity for this family of time distributions. 
Thanks in advance and I do appreciate your help.
Best,
HRJ

Comment: What do you mean with "time distribution"? Is the parameter $t$ the time index? What do you mean with "linear distribution"?